# Selenium - Uploading image to website when input doesn't exist in HTML code and web uses SelectFileDialog

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this problem for I can't find proper solution.

On website trovo.live I'm trying to change profile picture with code. There is 'Upload' button, which opens SelectFileDialog.

When I try to find input tag via  document.getElementsByTagName("input") it doesn't find any input for uploading. (So I can't just do element.SendKeys() )

It works this way, when I select file in dialog then website converts it into data URI and set it as < img > *src*  + it sets style = transform: matrix(values params)
[image]

So I found this solution that I convert image into data URI and set it as *src* parameter like website do it. Also I calculate matrix parameter values.

My problem is when I click save button later, website for some reason resets my css style and then picture is saved with bad positioning

After I change *src* by code (transform style remains from previous avatar)

[image]

This is how it looks when I upload manualy by Upload button or I can matrix() values [image]

But when I click save button, it saves like that first picture, like it wouldn't count in my matrix() values. Can I somehow get into save button function and force in my matrix() edit? Or simulate Upload function without pressing button?
Or how can I handle selectFileDialog in selenium when

1. No < input > in HTML code
2. I can't use System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(path);

I also tried to use AutoItX, but I had some problems with their library in my project and I would like to handle it without libraries if possible.
Thank you very much for all answers :)

**edit
I found .js file which contains code for it, but I have no idea how to call for example method for resizing on method image [code for javascript](https://prettier.io/playground/#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)

Comment: By accident I found object 'cropper' which contains method where I can pass data URI and set avatar successfuly. So this is solved